# Why has a diffeomorphism full rank?

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Let $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $U$ open, be a diffeomorphism, i. e. $f$ is bijective and $f,f^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable. Why does the Jacobian $f'(x)$ has full rank for all $x \in U$?

(It's clear that if $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f'(x) \neq 0$ then f is locally invertible (inverse function thm.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth. Then $f^{-1}\circ f = \mathrm{id}$, and the chain rule shows that
\begin{align}
\forall x \in U~ \mathrm{d}f^{-1}(f(x))\circ \mathrm{d}f(x) = \mathrm{id}
\end{align}
thus, $\mathrm{d}f(x)$ is invertible.